# Validity and legitimacy of a non-Kosher High Priest

Tags: history, beis-hamikdash, kohen-priest

IIRC, in the second half of the Second Temple, starting with the Hasmonean revolt, many High Priests were either illegitimate (breaking Zadok's lineage), self-proclaimed, Sadducees, or appointed by ruling gentiles.

What is the legitimacy of such an appointment, are his acts, especially Yom Kippur works, valid Halachicly, and are there any implications for laymen coming to the Temple?

Comment: Wasn't the fact that they all died on yom Kippur proof their acts were invalid?

Comment: @robev All? Seriously? I don't think they would take the job if that speculation was true. Also who do you refer as "they"? Hasmoneans?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31092/sadducee-kohanim-gedolim-dying-on-yom-kippur